# Androguard "internal" vs "external" classes

Tags: android, apk, androguard

I am trying to get the API calls from the Android apk source code. I am currently using Androguard and it differentiates between *internal* and *external* classes/methods. I assume that the external relate to classes not compiled in dex format, thus belonging to third-party libraries (i.e., java, etc.) whereas internal relate the application own defined classes and methods. I have been exploring this concept, but I found no resource explaining that. Not even in Androguard documentation. Is my assumption true.

Answer (score 0):

An external class or method is simply a class or method which could not be found inside the loaded DEX files at the time the XREFs were created! Thus, it is important to always load all DEX files of a multidex file. On the other hand, beware that classes might not be defined as they could be loaded dynamically later. External does not automatically mean that this class/method is an Android or Java API! See: https://androguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intro/xrefs.html